# Can we call a paid API a SaaS?

Tags: api, software-as-a-service

Is it technically correct to call a paid API, e.g. [APIs](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html) provided by TimeAndDate.com, a SaaS?

The reason of asking is that I was having a discussion with someone who was of the view that we can't as for a SaaS there should be a software which end-users interact with and I was of the opinion that 'Software' is an umbrella term for dozens of things including APIs as well. So paid APIs are also Software as a Service model.

Comment: What is your definition of SaaS? Does this site fit your definition of SaaS? If yes, then you can call it SaaS, according to your definition of SaaS, if not, then you cannot.

Comment: Service as a Service?  Sure, why not?  ;-)

Comment: `Is it technically correct to call a paid API, e.g. APIs provided by TimeAndDate.com, a SaaS?` Are they selling software or data? If they are not selling the former, then no, it's not technically correct.

Comment: So, @Laiv you think an API is not a software? Or did you mean to say 'business application' instead of 'software'?

Comment: Yes, it's. But TimeAndDate is not "selling" the software that provides you with the data, it's "selling" data. Happens that they still need to provide a way for customers to consume the data (an api web).

Comment: SaaS is a software distribution model. It has nothing to do with software design, software properties, etc. Those are technical concerns. SaaS is marketing and sales concern. Some illuminated in Microsoft wanted to leave its imprint in the history with a new buzzword. SaaS is the old idea of running software remotelly. Software that usually customers run within their own infrastructure. The last "S" of SaaS is where the business lays. Service: maintenance, update, configuration, sizing, scalling, distribution, etc. Whether the software has UI or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think a paid web service counts as SaaS.  For true SaaS, the idea is that the software is hosted and distributed from the provider centrally.   Its more or less a turn key solution which requires minimal effort from the customer.  The customer should need to little or no maintenance to use and receive updates to the application(s).

SaaS is also done via a subscription model, where you pay to use the software year after year, vs a one time perpetual license.  Consider the difference between Office 365 and Office 2016.  The former gets me the latest version right now, and I continue to receive updates as long as my subscription is maintained.  With 2016, I get the 2016 version, maybe some updates, but I won't get Office 2017+ unless I pay again.  However, if I stop paying the subscription, I would lose access to Office 365.

In your case, your customers still need to build software to interact with your web service.  That's the issue; with SaaS, the customer just starts a subscription with you and they can begin to use your software.  When they no longer want/need it, they cancel the subscription.

Comment: You only described half of what a SaaS is or what it provides. The idea beneath SaaS is to make customers to forget anything related to the implementation and maintenance of software that is usually deployed within customer's infrastructure. In that "gap" literally fits any piece of software we can run on the cloud or on a workstation as soon as the only requiered for the customer to access to It is internet. The software itself doesn't matters as much as the service of maintenance involved.

Comment: Google Firebase can be a good example. Up untill now, some of its services were free and involved customer's to develop their own solutions around It. Cloud messages are a good example. APIs are just one of the many possible interfaces to access a logic (service) that runs somewhere. As soon as the customer should not be worried about the "how, where and when" It could be labeled as SaaS. On the other hand, SaaS is a buzzword coined by and for sales and marketing. It has very few technical meaning.

Comment: Isn't the only difference between your definition of SaaS and OP's proposed application the degree of UI that is provided to a user? Where do we draw the line on the minimum UI requirements needed to be considered SaaS?

Comment: @Flater The difference between the OPs service and SaaS is the fact that his customers must build their own software to use his service.  With SaaS all the software you need to use the software must be included.

Comment: @Laiv I added another sentence which hopefully makes this clear, but what you're describing is what I meant by "hosted and distributed."

Comment: @Laiv I would not consider Firebase SaaS.  Its an SDK, and we've had those for a while.  Office 365 is SaaS; Office 2016 is not.  And certainly anything that would require the customers to involve their own software engineers to get the value of the subscription wouldn't be SaaS.

Comment: `Isn't the only difference between your definition of SaaS and OP's proposed application the degree of UI that is provided to a user? Where do we draw the line on the minimum UI requirements needed to be considered SaaS?` there's no need of UI. Not all the software needs UI. It's the service involved beneath the software what make It SaaS.

Comment: @Laiv For SaaS, yes, there must be some kind of UI, because SaaS is sold to **end users**.  An API which a company buys, but then must invest more money on buy paying someone to code **more** software to get the value defeats the purpose of SaaS.

Comment: The whole prupose of SaaS is to make customers believe they no longer need to run the software on on-premise CPDs. "We run It for you","we do maintenance for you","we do keep It updated for you","we scale it for you", and so on. End user can be devs too, what you call UI could be a mere web console or dashboard addressed to set variables related to the SaaS. Or not even that, how is the case of DBaaS. And yes, DBaaS is SaaS too. Or would not you consider  DB to be software?

Comment: @Laiv Yes, and you can have client software on the customer's device which is updated automatically (ClickOnce, Play Store, Windows Store, etc.) and still have the customers not doing maintenance or very little.  Developers can be end users; getting Visual Studio by buying a VS Subscription meets that.  I never said the UI couldn't just be a web console; a UI in a browser is still SaaS.  I said that an API **by itself** cannot be SaaS; it is incomplete, and requires a software engineer to build the client.  SaaS is a **complete** software package.

Comment: @Laiv Software does not exist for its own sake; it exists to do something *useful*.  If you just buy an API, by itself that is not useful.  You must create *more* software to use it.  Which means it is not SaaS.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that [TimeAndDate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html) does appear to be a SAAS service.

They offer a software service (though it appears a fairly  **modest** one), and they appear to host it themselves (they have limits on request counts).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)

> Software as a service (SaaS /sæs/)[1](https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html) is a software licensing and
>   delivery model in which software is licensed on a subscription basis
>   and is centrally hosted

Perhaps I misunderstand some aspect of the question, as the answer appears pretty obvious. And the question is partly garbled:

> a discussion with someone who was of the view that we can't as for a
>   SaaS

Perhaps if you correct / clarify the question I can change my answer ;-)

Comment: I think most reasonable people define software as "applications," not programmer API's.

Comment: Well, I've been accused of many things, but reasonableness is not one of them ;-). I cannot say what 'most reasonable people' would think about this. But it never occurred to me to NOT consider a UI-less collection of webservices an application. I've even built many of them ;-). I cannot say for sure they were called 'applications'. But they were definitely called 'services' and sold (or used) as such. I KNOW this is not dispositive, but wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) says "an application is a computer program designed to help people perform an activity". No GUI

Comment: Wikipedia's definition is the most vague definition of anything that I've ever seen.  However, I've given it some thought and realized that I use "software" to mean, simply, "computer code," so I've upvoted your answer accordingly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I suggest that maybe Wikipedia's definition is vague, because its defining a word, whose meaning is vague ;-) https://www.bartleby.com/73/2019.html

Comment: I do think a key part of SaaS is that the software is ready to use, and not something that a customer needs to spend more money on building and maintaining a portion of the solution themselves.

Comment: @Andy I'm a programmer and I buy stuff. Are you saying that I'm not allowed to buy software? I think the confusion here - is over who the customer is, and what they want, and what constitutes software ready to use. If I want an email client, Office365 might be software ready for my use. But if I want (OK - their product offering is ridiculous) - "styff computed about dates" - why is that not a legitimate thing to want? Do you think google maps is a legitimate SAAS? I've used that on projects with no GUI - just to measure distances between addresses.

Comment: @LewisPringle I'm saying if you buy something and then have to write your own software to use it, you didn't buy something considered SaaS.    I have a subscription to Visual Studio; Visual Studio is SaaS.  As long as I keep my subscription current, I can use VS.  When I end the subscription, I can't.  But VS arrives to me as a complete IDE, ready for me to use it for its purpose.  I don't get a set of APIs which I then need write software against to actually have an IDE.  No, Google Maps is not SaaS.  Its APIs which provide value, but I need to provide..

Comment: … further value to make it useful (probably to someone else).

Comment: RE: Google maps:  Google maps in the browser is SaaS, I was thinking of Google Maps API, which a developer using would not be.

Comment: @Andy if it takes me longer to learn how to use Office365 than it took me to write code using the GoogleMaps API, does that mean Office365 is no longer SAAS? I think this is silly. Its software. Its provided - not in the form of a library - but in the form of a service. What are you going to call that? SAAS-x? These things all pass the duck test. They are SAAS.

Comment: @LewisPringle SaaS is a complete software package, immediately usable directly for their intended purpose; APIs are not.  It has nothing to do with learning.  If you are required to write code to "use" the software, its not SaaS.  You don't need to write your own program to work with the software you purchased just to make it work.

Comment: @Andy Do you disagree with the wikipedia  definition? When people talk past one another like this it's usually because they are talking about different things. I offered clearly the definition of saas I applied. I cannot imagine you don't see how the Google maps api and this time site meet that definition.  If you seriously disagree then please provide a reference to your alternative definition and and explanation as to why that is a better source for the definition

Comment: @LewisPringle The wikipeida definition seems reasonable, and aligns pretty much with my POV, which is that SaaS provides software to end-users.  Google Maps API does not count because it is incomplete and missing the client portion.  The Google Maps *website* is the client to the API, and **is** SaaS (which people "pay" for by seeing ads).  But if you buy access to use the API, you still do not have functioning software; you must code a client to complete the value, which is *not* SaaS.  The value of SaaS is that you can being using it pretty much immediately (as the examples on WP do).

Comment: If u agree with the wikipedia definition  then kindly reread it and restrict your reasons for how Google maps is not saas to things actually mentioned in the definition.   None of your objections are in any way even hinted at in the definition

Comment: What about salesforce.com. I've never used it but I'm told almost nobody uses it without customizing it with scripting.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the de facto definition of Software as a Service, is that the software must be something you would 'in the old days' bought a copy of and installed on your computer.

So Office 365 can be a SaaS because the 'old way' was to buy MS Word on a CD. But Google Mail isn't because no-one buys an email client in a shop.

Comment: While I roughly agree with the intentions behind the "SaaS" label; I find the examples you used a bit iffy, since Gmail (which is more than just the underlying email service) competes with Outlook, which is in fact no different from Word in that it is part of the "old way" of buying and installing Microsoft Office. Note that both Gmail and Outlook are more than just email clients (calendar, scheduling, ...)

Comment: @flater I think the key difference is people don't buy outlook. people buy exchange server

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. Outlook and Word are both part of Microsoft Office. If you consider Word 365 as SaaS because it used to be part of Office, then so is Outlook 365 since it was also part of Office. And if Outlook 365 is SaaS, then Gmail is too since it delivers the same service in the same way.

Comment: @Flater technically, there is no difference. but thats my point

Comment: It's confusing if the example you give is the polar opposite of the point you're trying to make.

Comment: its the best example, because no-one thinks of gmail or outlook etc as SaaS

Comment: No, I actually do buy outlook (as part of Office 365).  There's no requirement I use it to talk only to an Exchange server, Outlook works just fine talking to my ISPs email server.  And I think there is a difference between Outlook which comes with 365 vs. Outlook 2016; the former actually being a subscription and the latter being a one time perpetual license.

Comment: RE: gmail vs. outlook, gmail would be SaaS (you pay by seeing ads), Outlook may or may not, depending on the license you chose to get it.

Comment: I purchased Eudora "the old way" back in the day. It came on a CD (or possibly floppy?).

Comment: yeah, the point is its NOT SaaS regardless of the technical similarity